# Javascript comparison algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**Question:** How to iterate through a hash to check for a value? Find a name that matches the input

**Explanation:** I'm sure there is an easy way to to do this, but I just want to learn more honestly... More than likely we are going to handle this process on the backend, but I just wanted to attempt this process. Our observable is bringing back a hash of providers and I would like to iterate through all of them and find any values that match the input value.

**My understanding so far:**
I know I will need to iterate through all of the hashes and compare each key to my input, and return that.

```
    value is equal to the user input
    for (let key in serviceProvder) {
        if (value = serviceProvider[key]){ 
           return key
        });
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you should reverse your hashtable? And you know that `=`, `==` and `===` are different?

Comment: or maintain two hash tables, one that is a reverse lookup.

Comment: there is also a typo in `let key in serviceProvder` (the `i` is missing in `Provider`)

Comment: As already suggested, since a JavaScript object is technically a hash table there's no need to look up anything because the language will do it for you—as long as the provider hash is stored as *key*, not *value*. Do you do it that way because there can be different providers with the same hash?

Answer (score 0):

replace "=" by "===" and correct the spelling typo  for serviceProvider and it should work just fine :D

Answer (score 0):

In ES6 you can do

```
var objArray = [
    { name: 'Object 0', otherProp: '321' },
    { id: 1 },
    { otherProp: '850' }];

var value = 1;


var obj = objArray.find(function (obj) { return obj.id === value; });
Object.keys(obj) // ["id"]
```

Or Using Underscore.js

```
var obj = _.find(objArray, function (obj) { return obj.id === 1; });
Object.keys(obj) // ["id"]
```